# Custom images for LXC deployment

Tags: linux, lxc, lxd

With docker you can build a custom image by starting with a base OS image from the community such as Ubuntu, or Alpine, then install your app and any other dependencies (ngnix for example). Then quickly deploy that image as a running container whenever you need with everything ready out of the hood.

How do you achieve the same thing with LXC? For example customizing a base OS image (such as centOS) with all your software (such as nginx) installed and pre-configured so that you can quickly deploy a fully functional container right out the box?